# How to know a semiconductor is p type or n type from hall effect calculations?

Tags: electricity, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-hall-effect, hall-effect

Using the hall effect calculations how can we determine a semiconductor is p type or n type

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to break it down from a Hall effect measurement is that if the voltage produced is positive, then the semiconductor is *p*-type and *vice versa* if the voltage produced is negative. The cause is the majority charge carrier being either the electron or the hole - as the charge carriers are moved through the hall effect, the electric field will be built up. If the majority carrier is the electron, the field will be in one direction, but if it is the hole it will be the opposite.